# R RODBC hangs on UPDATE

Tags: r, rodbc

Pretty simple operation... I am using RODBC and doing other things (selects, inserts, etc.) with it in a script, but when I get to this it hangs. The update statement works fine in TOAD.

```
sqlQuery(conn, "UPDATE MOLBIO.FUSION_PARTNER SET AA_SEQ_ID = 4000, VERSION = 2 WHERE DISPLAY_NAME = 'blah'")
```

Is there a reason it wouldn't execute an UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 0):

There were uncommitted transactions on the table I was trying to update. Once those were committed, everything worked find.